# I am using jinja and want to pass a variable into a URL but it is now happening.

Tags: python, html, django-templates, jinja2

```
{% for x in data %}
  <tr class="table-row">
      <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
      <td><label>{{ x.0 }}</label></td>
      <td><img src="{% static 'lang/hi_IN/font/**x.1**' %}"></td>
      <td><label style="font-size:20px">  {{ x.2 }}</label></td>
      <td><input style="font-size:20px;text-align:center" type="text" value={{x.2}} size=3 title="Text"></td>
        <td><label> {{x.3}}</label></td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to pass this **x.1** value to the url so how can i do that? value 0f **x.1** is like **images/1.jpg**.

Comment: You say you use jinja2 but`{% static ... %}` is DTL syntax, so which one is it ?

Comment: @polku so what should i use instead of `{% static ... %}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to jinja2 templates and mostly I work with Flask, but with jinja2  I would try this:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='lang/hi_IN/font/')}}{{x.1}}">
```

And this is blind guess that I came up after reading about **static** in Django-Templates (from this [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#static)):

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "images/" %}{{x.1}}" alt="img" />
```

Comment: This will work. But I also tried different possibilities earlier and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have never used jinja or django, but I believe you just need to separate the variable form the string.

```
<td><img src="{% static 'lang/hi_IN/font/' + x.1 %}"></td>
```

or the equivalent of this in jinja.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `static` keyword in Jinja2. Maybe everything is much simpler:

```
<td><img src="lang/hi_IN/font/{{ x.1 }}"></td>
```

Or the problem may be deeper. Did you implement serving methods? It should looks like:

```
@app.route('/media/<path:filename>')
def media(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['MEDIA_FOLDER'], filename.encode(app.config['ENCODING']))
```

Comment: This is syntactically correct. So, what do you have with static serving?
[This](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#static-files) link may be usefull.